# Can I set user ID using Measurement Protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

If I send a request like this via Measurement Protocol:

> v=1&tid=UA-123456-2&cid=455646456.4646456456&uid=123

What will happen? Given that UID **hasn't** been set on the site before.
Will this request associate the provided client ID with user ID `123`?
Or can I only provide a UID that has already been set on the website like this:

> ga('set', 'userId', USER_ID);

Answer (score 3):

The javascript tracker is build on top of the measurement protocol and basically all a "set" call does is to add a parameter to the eventual tracking url; it does not perform any special magic that enables user id tracking.

The tracking works the same way if you create the tracking url via some other way, [you can use anything that's in the parameter reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid).

> Given that UID hasn't been set on the site before.
>   Will this request associate the provided client ID with user ID 123?

That depends on whether or not you've enabled [session unification](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4574780?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: are you saying that if I enable session unification and send user ID 123 via a Measurement Protocol alongside client ID, GA will associate the provided client ID with user ID 123?

Comment: The rules for session unification are documented here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4574780?hl=en, but broadly speaking, yes.